# Inverse Fourier Transform Convolution

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution, fourier-transform

There were similar questions but I am having trouble inferring a solution from them.

Assume all integrals are $\pm\infty$

I am supposed to prove that $$F^{-1}[Y_1(w)Y_{2(w)}] =\int y_1(t-\tau)y_2(\tau)d\tau$$

I have made some substitutions starting from the definition of the inverse Fourier transform and have gotten to here:

$$F^{-1}[Y_1(w)Y_{2}(w)] = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int [\int y_1(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt ] [\int y_2(\tau)e^{-i\omega \tau}d\tau] e^{i\omega t'}d\omega$$

I then use the delta function projection property to project out t' and end up with the end result except there is an extra 2$\pi$

where does the 2$\pi$ go from that step to the ending step?

$$F^{-1}[Y_1(w)Y_{2}(w)]=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int \int  \delta (t-t'-\tau) y_1(t)dt  y_2(\tau)d\tau$$

how do I get rid if the 1/2$\pi$?

Comment: Show that $\mathcal{F}[y_1 \ast y_2](\omega) = Y_1(\omega) Y_2(\omega)$ then use the Fourier inversion theorem. The $1/2\pi$ appeared because you didn't substitue $\delta$ correctly (also how do you make this substitution rigorous ?)

Comment: There's no 2pi factor in any expresison of the delta function can you show me what you mean please?

Comment: In the **sense of distributions** $\delta(x) = \lim_{A \to \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-A}^A e^{i \omega x}d\omega$. This is more or less equivalent to the Fourier inversion theorem for distributions. Can you show instead that if everything converges then $\mathcal{F}[y_1 \ast y_2](\omega) = Y_1(\omega) Y_2(\omega)$  (where $\ast$ is [the convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem)) ?